# Optimizing HTML5 video for best quality

Tags: html, video, optimization, mp4

I have a 3 minute video I'd like to embed on a web page. The problem is that despite best efforts, the file size of the video ends up being over 30 mb. I would like the size to be near 10 mb. I have over-compressed the video to the point where it is barely watchable.

So far I have used fast start encoding, compressed bit rate and smaller frame size as low as 300 width, exported for web including moving the moov atom to the beginning. Still the file is too large.

How does one get hd mp4 video small enough for web without losing an insane amount of quality?

Comment: Try https://video.stackexchange.com/ you'll get better results

Comment: Can I cross post?

Comment: Just delete this post and post over there. When I need detailed info on video encoding, compression, resolution, etc. I get a solution in a couple of minutes usually.

Comment: Commented as should be deleted because it is unclear what you are asking. also there is a duplicate https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23046/optimizing-html5-video-for-best-quality